# Handling Foreign Key Data

Tags: sql-server

I'm new SQL in general and the structure/design of my database could be the issue. I am unsure on how to update the value of the foreign key when inserting a new row of data for Table 1 from my windows form application(VB.NET). When I insert the data what if there's more keys than users? I assume since foreign keys are based off on primary keys of another table in this case `user_id` I can't possibly have a higher `user_id` value in `user_id` (FK) than `user_id` (PK).

Example:

**Table 1**

```
key_id(PK) | key_name | key_info | access_group | user_id(FK)
-----------+----------+----------+--------------+-----------
        1  |    key 1 | someinfo |      group 1 |          1
        2  |    key 2 | someinfo |      group 2 |          1
        3  |    key 3 | someinfo |      group 3 |          1
        4  |    key 4 | someinfo |      group 1 |          1
```

**Table 2**

```
user_id(PK) | user_name | user_contact | user_address  | access_permission
------------+-----------+--------------+---------------+------------------
          1 |     Bryan |     11111111 | sampleaddress | group 1
```

**Edit**: the idea is that there are access groups for the keys so that way users only have access to certain groups of keys.

Comment: You should consider like, Table 1 can only has user_id which exists in Table 2. So even when you delete the data in Table 1 which will remove one user_id, you need to remove those in Table 2.

Comment: Sorry I'm not too clear on what you mean or how to achieve that

Comment: As long as the `user_id` value that you insert into `Table1` already exists in `Table2` then there is no problem. It's difficult to understand your issue - please post sample data. Typically you need to ensure there is a user to reference in the user table before you can create a record that references it. Otherwise you'll have records in `Table1` that don't have a `Table2` (user) record to point to.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Sorry there is no sample data available as I'm just at the designing stage, but I've updated the question for clarity

Comment: Well... this is you when you create dummy sample data to help you understand... but anyway: _When I insert the data what if there's more keys than users?_ Do you mean more records in `Table1` then there are in `Table2`? That is normal and expected. A single user might have many keys right? So there might be five users (user records) but 25 key records if they have five keys each.

Comment: Oh right, I was wrong to think that the user_id(FK) had to be exactly in sync with user_id(PK)... But what if I was planning to use the `access_group` in Table 1 and `access_permission` in Table 2 instead for the purpose of binding Users and Keys? The user_id(FK) is just there to 'link'(I'm not too sure of the correct naming) both tables together. Does that mean I can just insert dummy values into user_id(FK)? I'll update the table above for clarity.

Comment: @LimYX, no, not dummy. As I mentioned in my ans, inserting FK that does not have corresponding PK is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I can make a simple example

Lets say we have Table 2

like this

```
user_id(PK) | user_name
         1           A
         2           B
         4           C
         5           D
```

Please Notice that to use Foreign key in other table, you need to have **Table 2 set up first**.

Then, you start to create the `Table 1(key_id(PK) | key_name | user_id(FK))` that with Foreign key in `user_id`.

To safely add item to Table 2, you need query like this.

```
insert into Table 1 (key_name, user_id)
select *some_name, user_id from Table 2
where ....
```

This query won't insert any user_id not in Table 2, therefore it is **safe**.

So what will make you **Bloom~**?

Let's say I insert the Table 1 with arbitrary user_id.

```
insert into Table 1 (key_name, user_id)
values (*some_name, 3)
```

Oops, `3` is not in Table 2, sql will raise the error, and stop you from doing this.